# Swiping rows in a ScrollView disables scrolling

Tags: swiftui

I've created swipe-able rows that I've listed in a ScrollView. However when I try to scroll the list of rows in the ScrollView, the row swiping is triggered and the scroll is disabled. I'd like it recognize when I am trying to scroll and when I am trying to swipe.

I've tried increasing the `minimumDistance`, but that doesn't seem to address it.

Any ideas?

This is the `DragGesture`

```
let swipe = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { drag in
                self.itemPosition += drag.translation.width - self.oldDragDistance
                if self.itemPosition < 0 {
                    self.buttonsWidth = max(
                        self.buttonsWidth + -(drag.translation.width - self.oldDragDistance),
                        0
                    )
                }
                self.oldDragDistance = drag.translation.width
            }
            .onEnded { drag in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    if self.buttonsExpanded(at: self.itemPosition) {
                        self.itemPosition = -self.buttonsExpandedWidth
                        self.itemPositionOld = self.itemPosition
                        self.buttonsWidth = self.buttonsExpandedWidth
                        self.iconOpacity = 1
                    } else {
                        self.itemPosition = 0
                        self.itemPositionOld = self.itemPosition
                        self.buttonsWidth = 0
                        self.iconOpacity = 0
                    }
                    self.oldDragDistance = 0
                }
            }
```

And where I am including it in the `ScrollView`

```
ScrollView() {
                ForEach(userData.items) { item in
                    ItemRow(rowHeight: 64.0, item: item)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi @mikegee, consider posting your code, as it will help you get more replies, and more accurate too.

Comment: Done, thx for the tip.